# how to change ownership for files and folder at once

Tags: linux, shell, owner, file-ownership

in my plugin folder I've uploaded a few plugins true Wordpress. /httpdocs/wp-content/plugins I need to change the ownership of every file and folder form 48 48 to 10004 503 to not have any problems with the rights. how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chown -R 10004:503 /httpdocs/wp-content/plugins